# merge values of duplicated indices, where NaN and then keep first

Tags: pandas, numpy, interpolation, nan, data-cleaning

Lets say there is a large Timeindex-DataFrame `a` with some duplicates in the timeindices.

Some of those duplicated timeindices might contain NaNs, where the second/third/... duplicate does have a value.

How does one 'push the values up' into the `NaNs` above (so that they are filled) and afterwards drop every duplicate but the first? (this backward-fill should only happen between rows of the same datetime e.g. `12.06.2019 00:00:05`

Whats the appropriate/efficient way a way to do that with `pandas` or `numpy`?

```
Time                       A            B          C        D
12.06.2019 00:00:00   1.1412          NaN    1.21412  1.21412  
12.06.2019 00:00:01   1.1464      1.12643    1.21412  1.21412
12.06.2019 00:00:02      NaN      1.12634        NaN  1.21445
12.06.2019 00:00:02   1.1453          NaN    1.21423      NaN
12.06.2019 00:00:03   1.1536      1.12589    1.21445  2. 2452
12.06.2019 00:00:04   1.1612      1.12978    1.21445  4.12451
12.06.2019 00:00:05   1.1275          NaN        NaN      NaN
12.06.2019 00:00:05      NaN      1.12978    1.21445      NaN
12.06.2019 00:00:06   1.1612      1.12978    1.21445  4.12451
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1.1412,1.1464,np.nan,1.1453,1.1536,1.1612,1.1275,np.nan,1.1612],  'B':[np.nan, 1.12643,1.12634,np.nan,1.12589,1.12978,np.nan,1.12978,1.12978],   'C':[1.21412,1.21412,np.nan,1.21423,1.21445,1.21445,np.nan,1.21445,1.21445],   'D':[1.21412,1.21412,1.21445,np.nan,2. 2452,4.12451,np.nan, np.nan, 4.12451]}, indexpd.DatetimeIndex=["12.06.2019 00:00:00","12.06.2019 00:00:01","12.06.2019 00:00:02","12.06.2019 00:00:02","12.06.2019 00:00:03","12.06.2019 00:00:04","12.06.2019 00:00:05","12.06.2019 00:00:05","12.06.2019 00:00:06"])
```

expected result:

```
Time                       A            B          C        D
12.06.2019 00:00:00   1.1412          NaN    1.21412  1.21412  
12.06.2019 00:00:01   1.1464      1.12643    1.21412  1.21412
12.06.2019 00:00:02   1.1453      1.12634    1.21423  1.21445 
12.06.2019 00:00:03   1.1536      1.12589    1.21445  2. 2452
12.06.2019 00:00:04   1.1612      1.12978    1.21445  4.12451
12.06.2019 00:00:05   1.1275      1.12978    1.21445      NaN 
12.06.2019 00:00:06   1.1612      1.12978    1.21445  4.12451
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps filter out nulls?

Comment: @IronMan could you clarify, the way of filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Load the modules and data:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Time                       A            B          C        D
12.06.2019 00:00:00   1.1412          NaN    1.21412  1.21412  
12.06.2019 00:00:01   1.1464      1.12643    1.21412  1.21412
12.06.2019 00:00:02      NaN      1.12634        NaN  1.21445
12.06.2019 00:00:02   1.1453          NaN    1.21423      NaN
12.06.2019 00:00:03   1.1536      1.12589    1.21445  2.2452
12.06.2019 00:00:04   1.1612      1.12978    1.21445  4.12451
12.06.2019 00:00:05   1.1275          NaN        NaN      NaN
12.06.2019 00:00:05      NaN      1.12978    1.21445      NaN
12.06.2019 00:00:06   1.1612      1.12978    1.21445  4.12451
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
```

Fill missing values with zero:

```
ndf = df.fillna(0)
```

Do a `groupby` using `sum` which effectively replaces the zeroes with the previous values.
**Note:** This method does not work if both rows have values under the same column.

```
ndf.groupby('Time').agg({'A':sum, 'B':sum, 'C': sum, 'D': sum})
```

As last step, the zero values could be reverted to `np.nan`.

**UPDATE: take first value if there are no NANs**

First, create new data where under the same date there are no NANs. For 12.06.2019 00:00:02, I replaced under column A the NAN with 1.5 and under column B the NAN with 3.0.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Time                       A            B          C        D
12.06.2019 00:00:00   1.1412          NaN    1.21412  1.21412  
12.06.2019 00:00:01   1.1464      1.12643    1.21412  1.21412
12.06.2019 00:00:02      1.5      1.12634        NaN  1.21445
12.06.2019 00:00:02   1.1453          3.0    1.21423      NaN
12.06.2019 00:00:03   1.1536      1.12589    1.21445  2.2452
12.06.2019 00:00:04   1.1612      1.12978    1.21445  4.12451
12.06.2019 00:00:05   1.1275          NaN        NaN      NaN
12.06.2019 00:00:05      NaN      1.12978    1.21445      NaN
12.06.2019 00:00:06   1.1612      1.12978    1.21445  4.12451
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
```

Using the previous solution would result in an error since it would have summed the values anywhere.

First, like before, we fill NANs with zeroes.

```
ndf = df.fillna(0)
```

The following function (that we will use in the `groupby` command) inspects if there is a zero. If there is, it will take the sum of the data in the groupby category. If not, it will take the first appearing value.

```
def calcfunction(x):
    if any(x == 0 for x in x):
        return(sum(x))
    else:
        return(x.iloc[0])
```

The output of the following `groupby` shows for date 12.06.2019 00:00:02 in column A and B that only the first values are taken, while for column C and D there were NANs that were replaced with zeroes and summed with the other existing values.

```
ndf.groupby('Time').agg({'A':calcfunction, 'B':calcfunction, 'C': calcfunction, 'D': calcfunction})
```

Comment: What if there are `0`s in the dataset already?

Also: could you clarify what you mean by " f both rows have values under the same column."? -> because if there is a column, where the first duplicate row is already filled, then theres no need to fill it with the latter values (BUT: if theres NaNs in the other cols at this index, they should be filled though)

Comment: That's a good one. In that case I would first replace the zeroes temporarily by 999 so they cannot be replaced by values in the second row, and then after all set back to zero. What I mean is that my solution is problematic if for example at 12.06.2019 00:00:02 in column A there were no NANs but all values; in that case my code would sum the values undesirably. Let me give this a thought, I will be back tomorrow.

Comment: is there a way to (fastly) find a number that is guraranteed not in the column, without iterating over a large range( because that would take much time and RAM memory)?

Comment: @HR_quantile: you can do that by `(df['A'] == 1.1412).sum()` where you can replace 1.1412 by any value that you want to find. Please find the new solution that I added.